# List of theorems named after non-human animals

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, terminology, big-list

I think it would be entertaining if we could come up with a list of theorems named after non-human animals (so excluding names like "Gauss's lemma" and the like). So far, I have only encountered two, or if there's more I can't remember them:

$1.$ The Butterfly Lemma (aka the Zassenhaus Lemma in group theory)

$2.$ The Snake Lemma of homological algebra

Is anyone aware of any more theorems named after animals? And if so, why does it have the name it has?

(I'm also not sure as to whether or not I should tag this question as a soft question, as it seems that whether or not a theorem has such a name has an objective answer, but I am happy to edit if need be.)

Comment: I know some theorems named for foodstuffs.  the Sandwich Theorem, the Ham Sandwich theorem (they are different), the Pancake Theorem (it is the 2D case of Ham Sandwich), the Pizza Theorem.

Comment: @DougM I guess a lot of those are indirectly named after animals :)

Comment: `excluding names like "Gauss's lemma" and the like` Maybe you meant `Goose's Llama` ;-)

Comment: How about a book? Abstract and Concrete Categories; The Joy of Cats. http://store.doverpublications.com/0486469344.html

Comment: Birds On A Wire  (maybe). If n birds  randomly independently perch on a stretch of wire, what is the chance that each bird is its nearest neighbor's nearest neighbor? This is easily answered with some elementary formulae from Order Statistics. The 2-D version ( birds in a square) was answered in the late 20th century.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeon_hole_principle) (sorry Russians, I know you name it after Dirichlet and don't talk about the pigeons) is pretty classic:

If there are $n$  pigeons distributed among $m$ holes, at least two pigeons must occupy the same hole when $n > m$.

Now, this is certainly open to some debate: the theorem is really named after the holes, and not the pigeons. But, if the Bridge of Asses counts...

Comment: Ah should've thought of that one, but shouldn't it be when $n$ is strictly greater than $m$?

Comment: @leibnewtz I kicked myself when I finally did: I upvoted the question when it was initially asked (I think it's fun), but couldn't think of a single example at the time... :)

Comment: @leibnewtz And yes, I can neither read nor write in my current state, evidently. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you're willing to stretch slightly further to philosophy, [Buridan's Ass paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buridan%27s_ass) is a good one, especially if the ass is mathematically inclined.

In probability, there's the [infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem), because apparently monkeys can't read or write but there can be infinitely many of them.

Comment: If paradoxes count then [Achilles and the tortoise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Achilles_and_the_tortoise) as well.

Answer (score 6):

The Bridge of Asses  (Latin : Pons Asinorum) in Euclid. Here, ass does refer to the animal, not reknowned for its intelligence. The meaning is that an ass  cannot cross the bridge (by understanding the theorem).  The nuance is the converse: If you can't understand the theorem you are an ass and can go no farther in geometry.

Comment: I don't remember the theorem being named that way in high school geometry! Probably spared the teacher a headache, or maybe he was an ass himself

Comment: In the Merriam-Webster dictionary (on-line, via a linked reference in the Wikipedia article Pons Asinorum) it says the first known use of this name for the theorem is in the year 1751. I can understand high-school teachers' avoidance of such terminology in a classroom.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some mathematical theorems or solved problems named after farm animals:

> [King chicken theorem and other theorems about pecking orders](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Allendoerfer/1981/0025570x.di021114.02p00982.pdf) (with chicken comics!)
>
> [Archimedes' cattle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_cattle_problem)
>
> [Goat problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goat_problem)

Then there are mathematical objects (or related algorithms) named after animals:

> [Caterpillar tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caterpillar_tree), its cousin [centipede graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentipedeGraph.html), and the more distantly related [lobster graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LobsterGraph.html)
>
> [Crocodile dilemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrocodilesDilemma.html)
>
> [Hydra game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydra_game) (technically Hydra is mythical so this doesn't count but it's an interesting game.)
>
> [Ant colony optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some which, like the other answers, are not all strictly theorems:

- The [busy beaver function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver), a classic example of uncomputability
- [Dragon fractals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve), which I've seen appear in the theory of wavelets
- [The butterfly theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_theorem) in plane geometry. Note this is distinct from the butterly *lemma* which OP mentioned.
- [The Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) in analysis (kidding).

Comment: Not going to lie, I got a pretty big kick out of the Baire category theorem :)